# Do I need to manually write code to initialize UI control which is dragged and dropped from InterfaceBuilder?

Tags: swift, xcode, interface-builder

I'm a newbie.

I'm using Xcode 9.4 under macOS 10.13.5 and I'm writing a SingleViewApplication targeting iOS 11.4 with Swift 4.1.

I drag and drop a WkWebView to Main.storyboard and then made an referencing-outlet to my ViewController.swift and it's always nil.

Below is the screenshot.

By the way, my application in my simulator is always black.

I don't know why.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have 2 major problems in this code.
First, did you bind the webView to the code properlly? if not, (and because your a newbe in swift) i recommend you to watch this video below to understand how to make connection between your storyBoard and the code.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rnF_OkhzS-o

Second, you're checking if webView is nil. it will allways be nil because you don't applay anything to it.
get rid of this question and just applay the URL to it.

edit:

here is an example for how it supposed to look like:

```
    let url = URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com")
    let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    webView.load(request)
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to just apply the URL to it, and I got runtime error saying "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"